# List default content type across a site

Tags: 2013, list, powershell, content-type

Is it possible to list the Default Content type per Library via PowerShell?

Comment: do you want to get default content type in all lists in a give site?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of content types associated with a List. And the first one is the default one.

```
$webs = Get-SPSite http://siteurl | Get-SPWeb 

foreach ($web in $webs) 
{
    foreach ($list in $web.lists) 
    { 
        if($list.ContentTypes.Count > 0)
        {
            Write-Host "Default Content Type = " + $list.ContentTypes[0].Name
        }
    } 
    $web.Dispose() 
}
```